# Why is my code only returning true one time in comparing 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to solve a codewars problem and I can't seem to get my code to work.

```
a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11];
a2 = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19];

Test.assertEquals(comp(a1, a2), true);

  function comp(array1, array2){
     let newArray1Squared = [];
     let newArray1 = a1.sort(function(a, b){
     return a - b;
  });

  newArray1.map(function(num){
    newArray1Squared.push(num*num);
  });

  let newArray2 = a2.sort(function(a, b){
    return a - b;
  });

  for (let i = 0; i<newArray1Squared.length; i++){
    if (newArray1Squared[i] === newArray2[i]){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code so far. And the problem is:

Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (compSame(a, b) in Clojure) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a square, regardless of the order.

Examples Valid arrays

```
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]  
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
```

comp(a, b) returns true because in b 121 is the square of 11, 14641 is the square of 121, 20736 the square of 144, 361 the square of 19, 25921 the square of 161, and so on. It gets obvious if we write b's elements in terms of squares:

Comment: Hi charlieyin, if an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you're currently only comparing the first item in the sorted arrays. Any item other than the lowest will not be considered, because once the two lowest are compared, the function will either `return true` or `return false`.

After sorting, use an `every` check to see that every element in one array matches another:

```js
const a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11];
const a2 = [11 * 11, 121 * 121, 144 * 144, 19 * 19, 161 * 161, 19 * 19, 144 * 144, 19 * 19];
console.log(comp(a1, a2));

function comp(array1, array2) {
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  const arr1Sq = array1
    .map(num => num ** 2)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
  array2.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return arr1Sq.every((num, i) => array2[i] === num);
}
```

`.sort` has `O(n log n)` complexity, though. For larger inputs, better to use an object or Map instead, to collect the counts of occurrences, for an overall complexity of `O(n)`:

```js
const a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11];
const a2 = [11 * 11, 121 * 121, 144 * 144, 19 * 19, 161 * 161, 19 * 19, 144 * 144, 19 * 19];
console.log(comp(a1, a2));

function comp(array1, array2) {
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  const counts = {};
  for (const item of array1) {
    const squared = item ** 2;
    counts[squared] = (counts[squared] || 0) + 1;
  }
  for (const item of array2) {
    counts[item]--;
    if (counts[item] === -1 || Number.isNaN(counts[item])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is only called one time and ends when use the return statement. You are only checking the first value of the array.

You need to refactor your function to use the for loop outside and run the test in every cycle.

I thinks this works:

```js
a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11];
a2 = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19];


let newArray1 = a1.sort(function(a, b){
  return a - b;
});
let newArray2 = a2.sort(function(a, b){
    return a - b;
});

for (let i = 0; i<newArray1.length; i++){  
    console.log(comp(newArray1[i], newArray2[i])); //Run the test for every value in the array
}

function comp(value1, value2){
  let squareValue1 = value1*value1; 
  return squareValue1 === value2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using an object to store the occurrence count of each value in array 1, then go through array 2 and decrement the occurence count in the object, and finally you iterate through the object to see if all values are 0.

Check below:

```js
var a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11];
var a2 = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19];

function comp(array1, array2) {
  var temp = {};

  if(array1.length != array2.length)
    return false;

  for(let a of array1) {
    if(temp[a]) {
      temp[a]++;
    } else {
      temp[a] = 1;
    }
  }

  for(let a of array2) {
    let sqrt = Math.sqrt(a);
    if(temp[sqrt] && temp[sqrt] > 0) {
      temp[sqrt]--;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  var keys = Object.keys(temp);

  for(let key of keys) {
    if(temp[key] != 0)
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(comp(a1, a2));
```